# How to open modal for multiple components from same parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap, angular9

I am using angular 9.
I have a home page which has four buttons. I want to open separate modal on each button's click at a time.
I did research a lot, here is my trial and effort.
Thanks in advance :)

**parent component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-link-budget-view',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 
  @ViewChild('childOne') callChild_OneFn: ChildOneComponent;
  @ViewChild('childTwo') callChild_TwoFn: ChildTwoComponent;

  ...
  ngOnInit(): void {
     
  }
  openModalOne() {
    this.callChild_OneFn.OpenModalFunction();     
  }
  openModalOne() {
    this.callChild_TwoFn.OpenModalFunction();     

  ...
  }
}
```

**Home Html**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mr-2" (click)="openModalOne()">Modal 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mr-2" (click)="openModalTwo()">Modal 2</button>
 
...

 <app-child-one #childOne></app-child-one>
 
 <app-child-two #childTwo></app-child-two>

...
```

**childOne Component**

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-link-budget-view',
      templateUrl: './child-one.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./chile-one.component.scss']
    })

    export class ChildOneComponent implements OnInit {
      
     constructor(  private modalService: NgbModal) { }
    
     ngOnInit(): void {  
     } 
 
     OpenModalFunction() {
       console.log("component One function running...")
       this.modalService.open('#ModalOneId', { size: 'xl' });
     }    

      ...
      
    }
```

similarly there is a function in component two

```
OpenModalFunction() {
   console.log("component Two function running...")
   this.modalService.open('#ModalTwoId', { size: 'xl' });
 }
```

**Component One Html**

```
<ng-template #ModalOneId let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">This is modal one</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="card">
            <div class=" card-body">
                <div id="table" class="table-editable">
                  ...
                  ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="modal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

similarly ng-templete is used in component two html

Answer (score 1):

you didn't mention if what you wrote is working or not, or what errors you are getting. it looks like it should work to me. Although if you just want to open a modal, you can handle it completely in your html:

```
<button (click)="childOne.OpenModalFunction()">Modal 1</button>
<button (click)="childTwo.OpenModalFunction()">Modal 2</button>

<app-child-one #childOne></app-child-one>
<app-child-two #childTwo></app-child-two>
```

that should be the only thing you need in the parent. no code needed in the parent .ts file. if this is not working, there's something wrong with the code in your child class.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rick

Comment: I tried this method, but it is opening a white thin horizontal strip like model, childone printed on it. see... in child component ts `openModal() { 
    this.modalService.open('childOne', { size: 'xl' });
  }`  , in child coponent html `<ng-template> ... ... </ng-template>` in parent component ts ` @ViewChild('childOne') cc: childComponent;` and in parent html is - `<button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mr-2" (click)="cc.openModal('childOne')">General Parameters</button>
<app-general-parameters #childOne></app-general-parameters>`

Comment: Its not working, it opens a horizontal white line modal

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fixed it here is the code to help others

**Parent ts**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private modalService: CustomModalServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  openModal(modalName: string) {
    this.modalService.openModalFunction(modalName);
  }
}
```

**Parent html**

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mr-2" (click)="openModal('childOne')">Modal_1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mr-2" (click)="openModal('childTwo')">Modal_2</button>
```

**child one or two ts** code accordingly for one or two

```
export class ChildOneComponent implements OnInit {
 
  constructor(private modalRef: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  hideModalFunction() {
    this.modalRef.close();
   }
}
```

**child one or two html** for modal

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">This is modal one</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideModalFunction()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="card">
        <div class=" card-body">
            <div id="table" class="table-editable">
              ...
              ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="hideModalFunction()">Close</button>
</div>
```

and you need a custom modal service

**Custom modal service**

```
export class CustomModalService {
 ...
 private modalRef: NgbModalRef;
 constructor(  private modalService: NgbModal) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {  
 } 
 
 openModalFunction(modalName: string) {
       switch(modalName) {
         case 'one':
           console.log("component One function running...");
           // do any execution before opening child component
           this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(ChildOneComponent, { size: 'xl' });
           this.modalRef.componentInstance.testData = 'test';
           break;
         case 'two':
           console.log("component Two function running...");
           // do any execution before opening child component
          this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(ChildTwoComponent, { size: 'xl' });
          break;
         case default:
           // do nothing
       }
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating too much code here. You could make it more re-usable and less repetitive. Try to extract most of the business logic to a service. Leave the component as dumb(no business logic) as possible for better re-usability.

**Parent component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-link-budget-view',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  constructor(private myModalService: MyModalService)
  ngOnInit(): void {
     
  }
  openModal(modelName: string) {
    this.myModalService.openModalFunction(modalName);     
  }
}
```

**Home Html**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mr-2" (click)="openModal('one')">Modal 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mr-2" (click)="openModal('two')">Modal 2</button>
 
...
```

**MyModal Service**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MyModalService {
 ...
 private modalRef: NgbModalRef;
 constructor(  private modalService: NgbModal) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {  
 } 
 
 openModalFunction(modalName: string) {
       switch(modalName) {
         case 'one':
           console.log("component One function running...");
           // do any execution before opening child component
           this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(ChildOneComponent, { size: 'xl' });
           this.modalRef.componentInstance.testData = 'test';
           break;
         case 'two':
           console.log("component Two function running...");
           // do any execution before opening child component
          this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(ChildTwoComponent, { size: 'xl' });
         case default:
           // do nothing
       }
  }
  hideModalFunction() {
    //do something before closing the modal
    this.modalRef.close();
  }
}
```

Now no OpenModalFunction() required inside the child components as you have extracted the modal opening logic into the MyModalService. This will also adhere to the Single Functionality principle means every component has only single functionality to be fulfilled. Furthermore, you have now full control via MyModalService to handle popups. If you want to execute a common code before/after opening/closing the windows like notifying another service, you could do that.

Now this could be further optimized as all software codes do. Like extracting common code from Child Components to a single interface/abstract class. But it totally depends upon your requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much @Syed it is working fine, for closing modal i tried - 
`<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Component One</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close btn-sm" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideModalFunction()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">...</div>
 `

in  child.ts file

`hideModalFunction() {
    this.modalService.hideModalFunction();
  }`
it is showing circuler warning

Comment: It's expected as you are calling the Service from inside the child component and also we are using child component instance to open the popup from inside the Service. So dependency injector gets confused as which depends upon which. You may try using the NgbModalRef from inside the child component to get hold of the popup in order to close it, instead of using Service close method.

Comment: You don't have create any function in the component ts file to close the popup. Simply use modal.dismiss() from inside the child component html, to close the popup. Please refer to examples given in here https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: thanks again,  1. Circular warning is coming even if I am not using close modal functionality, Like I as of now I am only opening the modal. 2. **NgbModalRef from inside the child** is working fine, although calliing service  `this.modalService.hideModalFunction()` was also working fine 3. [ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples] (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)  it says -Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined.

Comment: 1. If Circular warning is still coming, that means you are still accessing MyModalService from inside of the child components. Please re-check all your child components and remove all the instances(even from constructor) of MyModalService. Make sure that MyModalService should only be accessed from outside of the child components like parent component. Can't help without seeing your code. 2. It will not build if you start and stop the ng serve, which is logical 3. Your child component html should contain <ng-template #content let-modal> for modal.dismiss to work properly.

Comment: i cant rid of circular warning :(